# How to disable livereload of gitbook

Tags: livereload, gitbook

I want to know how to disable livereload of gitbook.
I tried this:

```
"plugins" : ["-livereload"]
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There is a command line parameter `--[no-]live` that specifies whether live reloading is on(Default is true).
You can disable live reload by put this:

`gitbook serve --no-live`